# How to Wait for an element and do not fail if not found after a certain time xcuitest

Tags: xctest, xctestcase

In my application i have a two tab buttons say Tasks and Worklist. Tasks is always loaded. But Worklist button is dynamic and loaded only after some time.

I want to click Tasks button after a certain time. ie, i need to wait for Worklist button and if it exists after a certain time then click the Tasks button. Also if the timeout exceeds and Worklist button is not loaded then i need to click Tasks button.

i cannot use sleep.

Can i use expectationForPredicate and waitForExpectationsWithTimeout. But waitForExpectationsWithTimeout gets failed if the element is not found after timeout. Even if i write

```
waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(120) { (error) -> Void in
         click Tasks button
}
```

This gives stall on main thread.

I want to click Tasks button only after worklists is loaded. but if worklist is not loaded after some timeout, then also i need to click Tasks button..

Is there any solution. any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own custom Method to handle this:

```
func waitForElementToExist(
    element: XCUIElement,
    timeout: Int = 20,
    failTestOnFailure: Bool = true)
    -> Bool
{
    var i = 0
    let message = "Timed out while waiting for element: \(element) after \(timeout) seconds"

    while !element.exists {
        sleep(1)
        i += 1

        guard i < timeout else {
            if failTestOnFailure {
                XCTFail(message)
            } else {
                print(message)
            }

            return false
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

you can call the method like:

```
if waitForElementToExist(taskButton, timeout: 20, failTestOnFailure: false) {
    button.tap()
}
```

Hope this works for you!